# Validate decimal value to 2 decimal places with data annotations?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this in my view model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required")]
[Range(0.01, 999999999, ErrorMessage = "Price must be greater than 0.00")]
[DisplayName("Price ($)")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

I'd like to validate that the user doesn't enter more than 2 decimal places. So I'd like to have

**Valid values**: 12, 12.3, 12.34

**Invalid values**: 12., 12.345

Is there a way to validate this with a data annotation?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could use the RegularExpression attribute, with a regex that matches your criteria. There are a whole bunch of expressions here that involve numbers, I'm sure one will fit the bill. Here is the [link](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=2&categoryId=3).

This will get you started, though it may not be as inclusive as you want (requires at least one digit leading the decimal point):

```
[RegularExpression(@"\d+(\.\d{1,2})?", ErrorMessage = "Invalid price")]
```

Note that it is difficult to emit a precise error message because you don't know which part of the regex failed to match (the string "z.22" has the correct number of decimal places, for example, but is not a valid price).

Comment: This doesn't work for languages with decimal separator other than period (.), e.g. comma (14,6), because RegularExpression converts decimal to string using current culture.

Comment: How about `^\d*(\.|,|(\.\d{1,2})|(,\d{1,2}))?$`  which takes both period and comma, also allows no leading digits prior to the point or no digits after the point.

Comment: For some reason, given regular expression allows me to insert multiple decimal points, e.g.: 1.22.3.44

Comment: @jahav, checkout franck-duhaupas's answer that fixes your concern !

Answer (score 18):

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$",ErrorMessage = "Price can't have more than 2 decimal places")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

This will cater for 0 to 2 decimal places, or none at all.

Comment: You might want to escape the '.' (which means "any character" if not escaped) to give ^\d+\.\d{0,5}$

Comment: Oops, sorry meant ^\d+\.?\d{0,5}$ with the '?' to allow only 0 or 1 repetitions.

Comment: This doesn't actually allow a value with no decimal places i.e `10`, **However**, it does allow no decimal places with a dot: `10.`

Answer (score 6):

You can also create your own Decimal validation attribute, inheriting from [RegularExpressionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
 public class DecimalAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
 {
    public int DecimalPlaces { get; set; }
    public DecimalAttribute(int decimalPlaces)
        : base(string.Format(@"^\d*\.?\d{{0,{0}}}$", decimalPlaces))
    {
        DecimalPlaces = decimalPlaces;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format("This number can have maximum {0} decimal places", DecimalPlaces);
    }
 }
```

and register it to enable client-side validation in Application_Start():

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(DecimalAttribute), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+(\.\d)?$", ErrorMessage = "It cannot have more than one decimal point value")]
[Range( 0.1,100)]
public double xyz{get;set;}
```

It works for me upto one decimal value

Answer (score 3):

I had the same scenario as the OP, yet the answers provided don't give a solution that works for all of the following cases:

`12, 12.3 and 12.34`

To do that, we use the following regular expression:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+(.\d{1,2})?$")]
```

Answer (score 3):

To make it works for languages with decimal separator other than period (.) :

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Globalization;

/// <summary>
/// Decimal precision validator data annotation.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public sealed class DecimalPrecisionAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
  private readonly uint _decimalPrecision;

  public DecimalPrecisionAttribute(uint decimalPrecision)
  {
    _decimalPrecision = decimalPrecision;
  }

  public override bool IsValid(object value)
  {
    return value is null || (value is decimal d && HasPrecision(d, _decimalPrecision));
  }

  private static bool HasPrecision(decimal value, uint precision)
  {
    string valueStr = value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    int indexOfDot = valueStr.IndexOf('.');
    if (indexOfDot == -1)
    {
      return true;
    }

    return valueStr.Length - indexOfDot - 1 <= precision;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required")]
[DecimalPrecision(2)]
[DisplayName("Price ($)")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make this validation by using a regular expression and apply it with RegularExpression attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to **mattytommo**. You need to escape '.' - otherwise ANY character will be accepted

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$")]
```