# Decimal validation (data annotation)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I want to pass a decimal value to my controller. I use ASP.NET MVC with Knockout.js.

In my view I have:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.test, new { data_bind = "value: test", @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.test)
```

My ViewModel:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "error")]
[Range(0, Int32.MaxValue)]
public decimal test{ get; set; }
```

and I can't pass e.g 1,5 (with comma) because MVC validation doesn't allow me, if I pass 1.5 (with dot), controller doesn't have this value (it passed 0), but if I pass 5 it's work. 
Also if I turn off MVC validation and pass 1,5 (with comma) it's work.

Do you know how can I solve this problem ?
I would like to pass value with comma and dot.

Comment: You can look at using [jquery.globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize), or you can modify the client side rules - [example here](http://blog.degree.no/2013/04/decimal-validation-with-comma-in-mvc/)

Comment: You can use regular expressions : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10811563/1004522

Comment: On an official [ASP.NET tutorial](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view), there is an annotation for non-English culture computers running ASP.NET that says that you need to download _Globalize_ Nuget package in order to allow the use of ',' or '.' as decimal separator.

Answer (score 1):

This will allow positive values and you can pass in decimals. It validates numbers, with or without decimal places, and comma 1000 separators.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(((\d{1,3})(,\d{3})*)|(\d+))(.\d+)?$",ErrorMessage = "Error")]
[Range(0, Int32.MaxValue)]
public decimal test{ get; set; }
```

If you want to have a look at other regular expressions related to numbers, look [here](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=2&categoryId=3).

Comment: Hi @Ebad, how can you integrate this validation with Globalize library? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882732/validate-number-with-globalize-or-with-dataannotation-in-mvc

Comment: @Patrick Hope this helps: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/globalization-and-localization-of-model-validation-messages/