# Decimal value with 4 decimal place in TextBoxFor in ASP MVC

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

Need help adding validation on textbox field where the datatype of textbox is decimal and it can have max length of 15 digits or max length of 15 with 4 decimal places.

Example:
1234
123456789012345
123456789012345.1234

This is how part of the code looks like:

```
public decimal ShipmentWeight         { get; set; }
```

Razor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ShipmentWeight, new {@class = "form-control"})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ShipmentWeight)
```

Does anyone know how i can achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: You could use a `[RegularExpression]` attribute

Comment: tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558549/validate-decimal-value-to-2-decimal-places-with-data-annotations but didn't see any validation on UI end.

Comment: The following should work fine - `^\d{1,15}$|^(\d{1,10}\.\d{4})$`