# Entity Framework check for DbUpdateException before SaveChanges

Tags: entity-framework, savechanges

You will get a `DbUpdateException` if you try to save a string with length of 500 to a column in Sql Server which is a nvarchar(255).

Is there any way to check for this error before calling `SaveChanges()`? Maybe when adding the entity to context?

Comment: As the answer below states, yes you can do this. However, you really should be catching these errors before they become a problem. Validate the input before it gets anywhere near the context.

Comment: find the length of string and write comdition like if(len>255) throw err

Comment: @DavidG Yeah I've heard that you should validate before going to the context, but why is that? Because of performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to check for this error before calling SaveChanges? Maybe when adding the entity to context?

Yes. It is possible by calling this method [`GetValidationErrors()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.getvalidationerrors(v=vs.113).aspx) on your `DbContext` like below but you will get the validation errors result only if you make use of [data annoations attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx) on your entity classes

```
var validationResults = dbContext.GetValidationErrors();
```

`validationResults` will contain a collection of [`DbEntityValidationResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.validation.dbentityvalidationresult(v=vs.113).aspx) so if empty then your tracked entities are valid. Then calling `SaveChanges` just after will not throw exception about data validation but you can still get some others exceptions which can be checked only on server side e.g. concurrency exception, unique or reference constraint exception,  etc.

Comment: Ok great! StringLength attribute works! Is there any way to use data annotations attributes to check decimal length aswell?

Comment: Yes it exists => RangeAttribute.

Comment: Alright, but how would you define a range of 0 to 16 digits?

Comment: @skjold [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558549/validate-decimal-value-to-2-decimal-places-with-data-annotations/10811563) may help you.