# How do I prevent a user from adding more than two decimal places in textbox in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, decimal, viewmodel

Is there a way to not allow a user to add more than two decimals in a view textbox? I would like something similar to `[StringLength(5)]` when limiting a string, but for decimals.

In my current viewmodel:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Select the model of the vehicle you wish to sell")]
[Display(Name = "Price")]
public decimal? Price { get; set; }
```

In my view:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price) <span class="req">*</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Price, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "req" })
</div>
```

Currently, in the textbox, a user could type in 10.000000. I want to not let the user type more than 10.00.

I've tried many different resources on this site and others but none of them work. I would appreciate any help or a link to some other forum.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validate decimal value to 2 decimal places with data annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558549/validate-decimal-value-to-2-decimal-places-with-data-annotations)

Comment: @Martheen not quite. That will just give an error message if the user uses more than two decimals. I want it to block the user from entering more than two in the first place. Much like [StringLength(5)] wouldn't let a user type more than 5 characters in a string

Comment: Be careful that your web-app doesn't break for people in the rest-of-the-world (e.g. France or Germany) that uses a comma `,` for the decimal-place and a dot `.` for the thousands-separator.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to not allow a user to add more than two decimals in a view textbox?

To achieve the requirement, you can try to use the `RegularExpression` attribute to validate the format of the data.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})$")]
```

If client side validation is enabled, above solution would display error message while user input is not validate.

Besides, if you just want to prevent user from entering more than 2 decimal places rather than display client side error message, you can try to use some jQuery input mask, like below.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#Price").mask('00.00', { reverse: true });
</script>
```

Comment: This won't work for people in France or Germany, btw. And we shouldn't be using jQuery anymore in 2020. Consider using JavaScript's built-in `Intl` library: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl

Comment: Yes, for non-English locales that use a comma (",") for a decimal point.